Retrieving a particular Cookie Stored in the user's computer using c# on a Windows Machine, From Edge Browser
Screenshot of : Applications>Cookies>Site name>[Key value pairs of cookies]
Let's say I navigate to https://www.google.com/, and there's a cookie named XYZ. How can i retrieve that particular cookie using a C# console application.
What i tried until now:
string userProfilePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
string edgeUserDataPath = Path.Combine(userProfilePath, "AppData", "Local", "Microsoft", "Edge", "User Data", "Default");
string cookiesPath = Path.Combine(edgeUserDataPath, "Network", "Cookies");

tried to retrieve the path where these are stored, but there's no guide as to how to proceed further,
Any other methods can also be suggested.
TLDR; how to retrieve a cookie present inside edge browser for a particular site.
[edit]: This should be strictly ran inside one's own computer (local) to get the the browser's cookies in native.

This sounds super dodgy.

I know it sounds dodgy, I'm developing a c# executable that'd help me fetch a cookie that i need from my website, Instead of going there manually and copying it each time.

I understand this sounds fishy, but I'm just trying to make things easier for my self. Hope someone would get it

Just like any hacker. Browsers have restrictions to prevent exactly this. "From my website" why do you want to do that from outside the browser? You described what you assume the solution is (it's not), but what's the actual problem? Whatever it is, there are better, valid solutions.

@Bhavish hope someone would get it it doesn't matter what you want. Browsers are built to protect everyone. There are ways to use authentication and none of them involve reading cookies from disk. You can use HttpClient with a CookieContainer in code. If you want to automate the browser, you can using eg Playwright. You can also embed a browser inside your desktop application and control it

There's a cookie in my website that is used for authentication, normally i would go to my website and copy the cookie manually. and use it in a CLI tool that i have created to do some other tasks.

That's not how you do authentication. The cookie isn't stored in your website, it's sent by your website to your code/application. All the options I described work - use one of them to go to the web site and authenticate, then read the cookie stored either in CookieContainer, Playwright's BrowserContext.CookiesAsync or WebView's CookieManager.

Cookies are just small pieces of data that go back and forth between the server and the client using "headers" (part of the HTTP protocol). Those related to authentication tasks are usually created on the server side. If they are "persistent", they"re stored on disk for a while. They key point here is how would you use the retrieved cookie (as they're usually associated with the browser signature and other contextual information).

You can probably refer to Georgy's example and change that profile path from Chrome's into Edge's. Just make sure you have closed all Microsoft Edge tasks before you try to get cookies.
Anyway, just as the comment says, you may have better options to complete your task, depending on what you want to achieve, unless you only want to retrieve cookies.
